# ngclass with different conditions

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a div class="row" and I want to make some css styles depending on some variable cases.

this is how i did this

```
    <div class="row"
[ngClass]="{
  'case1': displayUseShortWarning === true,
  'case2': displayUseShortWarning === true && displaySellInCalifornia === true,
  'case3': displayNoWarningOnProduct === false          
}"
</div>


.case1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.case2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
}
.case3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
}
```

My question is how can I do the same thing with different code?
I don't like the fact that I have a lot of code in ngClass

Comment: You have 3 classes and 3 unrelated conditions for them respectively. It doesn't seem to get shorter than this.

Comment: Voted to close as people are taking your statement `I don't like the fact that I have a lot of code in ngClass` literally and just shifting it to another location, which doesn't serve any realistic purpose.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I think he wants to move this logic from template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find it that long.
to be honest, it is better for you to keep it that way.
Using a function will trigger it every cycle.
using booleans will trigger only when a value changes.

This is what I would do

```
<div class="row case" [ngClass]="{
  'case1': displayUseShortWarning,
  'case2': displayUseShortWarning && displaySellInCalifornia,
  'case3': !displayNoWarningOnProduct          
}">
</div>

.case {
    position: absolute;
}

.case1 {
    top: 0;
}

.case2 {
    top: 55px;
}

.case3 {
    top: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a custom directive which does apply and remove css-classes by using `Renderer2`. https://alligator.io/angular/using-renderer2/

Answer (score 1):

**ts file**

```
displayClass = [];
someCondition = false;

onSomeConditionSetting() {
    this.someCondition = !this.someCondition;

    if (this.someCondition === true) {
      !this.displayClass.includes('someClass') ? 
      this.displayClass.push('someClass') : '';
    } else {
      !this.displayClass.includes('someOtherClass') ? 
      this.displayClass.push('someOtherClass') : '';
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="row"
[ngClass]="displayClass">
</div>

<button (click)="onSomeConditionSetting()">Change Class</button>
```

I hope you get the idea. You can apply your own logic to remove classes as well.